# Why does chlorine oxidise iron to iron(III), not iron(II)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, transition-metals, oxidation-state

I was asked to predict the product of the reaction between iron metal and chlorine gas:

$$\ce{Fe +Cl2->} ?$$

The product here is supposed to be $\ce{FeCl3}$. But how would we know if the product is $\ce{FeCl2}$ or $\ce{FeCl3}$? Why should it be $\ce{FeCl3}$ and not $\ce{FeCl2}$?

Comment: Because it can. [Even iodine can oxidize iron to iron(III)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/154270/17175), if you have the right co-reactant anc controlled conditions.

Answer (score 3):

The enthalpy of formation ($\Delta H_\mathrm{f}^\circ$) of $\ce{FeCl3}$ is $\pu{-399.49 kJ mol-1}$, while the $\Delta H_\mathrm{f}^\circ$ of $\ce{FeCl2}$ is $\pu{-341.79 kJ mol-1}$. This means that $\ce{FeCl3}$ is $\pu{57.7 kJ mol-1}$ more stable than $\ce{FeCl2}$, a considerable amount. This means that it is more thermodynamically favorable for $\ce{FeCl3}$ to form than $\ce{FeCl2}$, likely due to the larger lattice energy.

Furthermore, in the +2 oxidation state, one electron remains paired in the $\mathrm{3d}$ orbital. When $\ce{Fe}$ is in the +3 oxidation state, however, it has a half filled $\mathrm{3d}$ orbital, a state which is known to be particularly stable, which you can read about further [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(chemistry)).

Comment: That's true, but I think there is more to the question. See, when you encounter some simple reaction, do you literally reach for the reference book to check the enthalpies? I don't think so. Then how do we really predict things like this? I imagine an ordered row of redox potentials (without numbers, just the order) and think in terms like "_OK, chlorine is strong, it will drive iron all the way to +3..._" But then again, maybe I am idealizing it, maybe we just remember all simple reactions and use the reference book for the not-so-simple ones?

Comment: This does not really answer it - it doesn't really matter which is more thermodynamically stable.

Comment: It is thermodynamically stable for diamond to spontaneously turn to graphite at room temperature. This does not mean we observe it to do so.